# What is the behaviour of Map.ofSeq with duplicate keys?

Tags: f#

What is the behaviour of `Map.ofSeq` when the same key occurs twice?

The [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/map.ofseq%5B%27key%2C%27t%5D-function-%5Bfsharp%5D) do not mention this case.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's test it empirically and find out...

This example:

```
[("key", 1); ("key", 2); ("key", 3)] |> Map.ofSeq
```

Produces the following result:

```
map [("key", 3)]
```

Whereas this example:

```
[("key", 3); ("key", 1);] |> Map.ofSeq
```

Gives this result:

```
map [("key", 1)]
```

Therefore, it seems that `Map.ofSeq` uses the last entry in the sequence with a given key when there are duplicates.

**EDIT**

As Fyodor Soikin pointed out, you won't want to rely on the undocumented behavior in your code.  Therefore, if you want to ensure a particular behavior for choosing a given value when there are multiple values with the same key in a sequence, you can use a function like the following:

```
module Map =
    let ofSeqWithDuplicates<'key,'value when 'key : comparison> (resolver: 'key -> 'value seq -> 'value) seq =
        let rec getDuplicates state remaining = 
            match remaining |> Seq.tryHead with
            | Some (key, value) -> 
                let newItem = Seq.singleton value
                let newState =                     
                    match state |> Map.tryFind key with
                    | Some existing -> state |> Map.add key (existing |> Seq.append newItem)
                    | None -> state |> Map.add key newItem
                remaining |> Seq.tail |> getDuplicates newState
            | None -> state

        seq
        |> getDuplicates Map.empty<'key, 'value seq>
        |> Map.map (fun key values -> values |> resolver key)
```

This allows you to pass a function called `resolver` that chooses the value from the list of duplicate values for a given key.  When using it with our first example from above, we can explicitly choose the minimum value like so:

```
[("key", 1); ("key", 2); ("key", 3)] 
|> Map.ofSeqWithDuplicates (fun key values -> values |> Seq.min)
```

So now we get the map:

```
map [("key", 1)]
```

Answer (score 8):

The [source code](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/blob/master/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/map.fs#L333) indicates that construction of a `Map` from a sequence is achieved via multiple calls of [`add`](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/blob/master/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/map.fs#L117), performed in the order of the source collection, thus resulting in the semantics of "last write wins".

However, since the documentation does not mention this property, it would be unwise to *rely* on it in production code. As it stands, this behaviour is an internal implementation detail, and could change in a subsequent version of the standard library.

Comment: Good point about not relying on undocumented behavior.  I've updated my answer to provide a way of deterministically choosing the value to put in the map when there are duplicates in the sequence.

Comment: In practice if one have an API where you suspect if you change the undocumented behavior it will make many users unhappy I would do my best to keep the behavior. Perhaps open a PR with a documentation change making it documented?